# How often is viewDidLoad called?

Tags: iphone

When the user switches to another program and then back again., the original program's view will be replaced by a new view from another program. So when the user switches back to the original program, would viewDidLoad be called the second time ?

Am asking this because if this is the case, then the initialization code placed inside viewDidLoad would be executed every time the user switches the screen back and forth.  And this could result in reseting views and loosing unfinished works of the user ...

Comment: The comment is not correct. It is called every time your view controller's view is loaded, not just the first time.

Comment: Leaving the app doesn’t trigger any **view** life cycle events.  Instead, it will fire off **application** life cycle events

Comment: @RobNapier you mean *if* the viewController is set to `nil` and later loaded again it's called again. Otherwise viewDidLoad doesn't get called again right?

Comment: @Honey If the ViewController is deallocated (because it has no strong references to it), or if `view` is set to nil. It is fairly uncommon to set `view` to nil anymore, but it was very common in older code (there used to even be a  `viewWillUnload` method that would be called, but it isn't called anymore).

Comment: @RobNapier I *believe* I'm aware of what deallocation and nilling do. What I'm not aware is **wether different ways of creating a viewController keep pointers to it or not** ie does **segue-ing** or **presenting** or **pushing** or **showing** a viewController act different ie some might just dealloc the viewController the moment it goes off screen and some still keep a pointing to it. [ I haven't found any question that discusses about a viewController's lifeCycle—relative to its inception. I only see answers saying: *it will stay as long as their's a strong pointer to it.*

Comment: @Honey that's the correct answer. Lifecycle doesn't include deallocation. It is reasonable to worry about deallocation for performance reasons, but you must never consider it for *correctness*. Your code must work correctly whether the view controller is deallocated or not. From a performance point of view, you mostly will have to profile. There are no real promises and behavior has changed at least twice (in iOS 6 and in a different way around table view cells in iOS 10). In rough terms, you'll probably be deallocated if you're not on the navigation stack of any tab, but this is not promised.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Don't do view controller initialisation in `viewDidLoad`. This is a common mistake.

For stuff that should only happen once when the view controller is loaded, do it in the controller's init method, like this:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)bundleOrNil
{
    if ((self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:bundleOrNil]))
    {
        //do your initialisation here
    }
    return self;
}
```

The `initWithNibName:bundle:` method is called *before* the view is loaded from the nib, and is only called once in the lifespan of the view controller.

The controller's view can be loaded and unloaded multiple times during the lifespan of the controller and `viewDidLoad` will be called every time. It may be unloaded whenever it's not on screen, usually if memory is low.

If you do set stuff up in `viewDidLoad` (e.g. adding subviews programmatically) you should always unset them again in `viewDidUnload`.

Think of `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidUnload` as being like the init/dealloc for the view property of the view controller. For stuff that relates to the views, create and release it in those methods. For stuff that relates to the controller itself, create and release it in `initWithNibName` and `dealloc`.

**UPDATE:** On iOS 6 and later, `viewDidUnload` is never called any more (unless the view is explicitly set to nil in the code), and so `viewDidLoad` will typically only be called once in the life of a view controller. This makes the advice above less critical, but it's still best practice, and still necessary if you need to support iOS 5 and earlier.

**UPDATE 2:** If you are loading your view controller from a Storyboard (which is now the recommended practice) instead of creating it programmatically then `initWithNibName:bundle:` will not be called. Use `initWithCoder:` or `awakeFromNib` to initialize your controller instead.

Comment: Hi, I have followed your advice but it seems like `initWithCoder:` is also called everytime the view load. I use storyboard.

Comment: @IsaA When you segue to a view controller in a storyboard, it initialises the view controller fresh each time it is displayed, so initWithCoder: will always be called. If you want to persist data while switching between views, you need to store it in a separate class outside of the view controller, such as the app delegate, or a separate singleton class.

Answer (score 17):

@Nick Lockwood provides excellent information, but there are a few more things to remember.

First, `initWithNibName:bundle:` is not called if the view controller is instantiated from a nib file or storyboard. In that case, `initWithCoder:` and `awakeFromNib` are called instead. This situation used to be somewhat uncommon on iOS, but with the addition of storyboards it is now much more common for view controllers to bypass `initWithNibName:bundle:`.

I recommend putting non-UI initialization code in a separate method (I call mine `setup`) and call it from both `initWithNibName:bundle:` and `awakeFromNib`. But I only do this if it's important that that initialization only run once. Otherwise I put it in `viewWillAppear:` to be as lazy-load as possible.

Second, you should not do anything that references `self.view` in `init...` or `awakeFromNib`. You should never reference `self.view` until `viewDidLoad` is called (otherwise you will force the nib file to be loaded sooner than it is needed). UI-related things should go in `viewDidLoad` if they're related to setting up the views, or `viewWillAppear:` if they're related to configuring the views (i.e. loading them with data).

So the way I usually set these things up:

```
@implementation

 - (void)setup {
  // Non-UI initialization goes here. It will only ever be called once.
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)bundle {
  if ((self = [super initWithNibName:nibName bundle:bundle])) {
    [self setup];
  }

  return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib {
  [self setup];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  // Any UI-related configuration goes here. It may be called multiple times, 
  // but each time it is called, `self.view` will be freshly loaded from the nib
  // file.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
  [super viewDidUnload];
  // Set all IBOutlets to `nil` here.
  // Drop any lazy-load data that you didn't drop in viewWillDisappear:
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];
  // Most data loading should go here to make sure the view matches the model
  // every time it's put on the screen. This is also a good place to observe
  // notifications and KVO, and to setup timers.
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
  // Unregister from notifications and KVO here (balancing viewWillAppear:).
  // Stop timers.
  // This is a good place to tidy things up, free memory, save things to
  // the model, etc.
}

- (void)dealloc {
  // standard release stuff if non-ARC
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObvserver:self]; // If you observed anything
  // Stop timers.
  // Don't unregister KVO here. Observe and remove KVO in viewWill(Dis)appear.
}

@end
```

Comment: A bit late to the party, but one tweak I'd recommend is calling [super awakeFromNib] in -(void)awakeFromNib.   "You must call the super implementation of awakeFromNib to give parent classes the opportunity to perform any additional initialization they require. Although the default implementation of this method does nothing, many UIKit classes provide non-empty implementations. You may call the super implementation at any point during your own awakeFromNib method." - http://bit.ly/178MFt4

Answer (score 6):

`-viewDidLoad` will be called once whenever the view controller needs to load its view hierarchy. Obviously, that'll happen the first time that the controller accesses its view. If the view controller later unloads its view, then `-viewDidLoad` will be called again the next time the view is loaded. A view controller won't unload its view just because the view is hidden, but it might do so if memory starts to run low.

A view controller should know the state of its views and be able to set them up as necessary in its `-viewDidLoad` method. Views shouldn't be used to store state -- nothing should be irrevocably lost just because the view is unloaded.

Comment: About "A view controller should know the state of its views", wish to ask this "ability to keep the state" is the responsibility of our custom code or is it built-in in the Cocoa library ?

Comment: It's not built-in. The point is that your view controller shouldn't count on views to hold state. For example, if you've got a slider in your view, your view controller should remember that slider's value whenever it changes. That way, if the view is unloaded and then loaded again, the view controller can reset the slider to that saved value in -viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 5):

> So when the user switches back to the original program, would
>   viewDidLoad be called the second time ?

(Above is from the op)

In those cases there are two methods to be called:

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application;
```

reopening a backgrounded app (from task manager or from springboard again)
unlocking device which is locked when the app is active.

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

after phone calls
notification center dismissal
task manager dismissal (double tap home button & double tap again)

Answer (score 4):

From [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidLoad):

> This method is called after the view controller has loaded its associated views into memory.

So, it is called whenever the view controller has its views loaded into memory.  This could be the first time the view is loaded and never again, or every time the view is made visible if your view unloads constantly (`viewDidUnload` due to memory constraints, etc.)