# Passing/Inject ManagedObjectContext into view controllers

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am trying to do the right thing by passing my MOC into the view controllers that need them.  I am using a third party lib to create a Side/Navigation menu and I am having trouble figuring out how to get my MOC through from the SideController into my ViewControllers that do the work.

Started with this (easy part) Step 1:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    LoginViewController *rootView = (LoginViewController *) self.window.rootViewController;
    rootView.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
}
```

Then after my user logins in I pass it one to the third part controller (still ok here) Step 2:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    NSString *segueIdentifier = [segue identifier];
    if ([segueIdentifier isEqualToString:@"LoginSegue"]) {
        TheRootViewController *rootViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        rootViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    }
}
```

Here is the third part code Step 3:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{

...
    MyNavigationController *navigationController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"contentViewController"];
    navigationController.managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;
    self.contentViewController = navigationController;
...
}
```

My problem is this, the code in Step 3 (awakeFromNib) gets called before my segue in Step 2 has a chance to set the MOC on RootViewController.

Basically all examples I can find are using storyboards all the way through, but I have somewhat of a hybrid since my third party app uses code.  How do I get the MOC to TheRootController before the awakeFromNib gets called?  Is that even possible.  Is there another way?

I am really early on in the project and would like to not start stuffing things in the AppDelegate but struggling with figuring out how to do the right thing in the midst of a third party app.

Comment: If your Core Data usage is relatively trivial, I would dare to suggest wrapping all the core data stack in a singleton object. This approach has several weak points of course, but it could suit you if you have too much of third party code to adapt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you'd like to stick to passing the MOC from controller to controller, you could simply move your awakeFromNib code that references the MOC into viewDidLoad.  viewDidLoad will be called after the prepareForSegue function completes.

I'd also like to add that is indeed a bad idea to stuff the MOC into the AppDelegate.  But as @spassas suggests, it might be a good idea to use a singleton object that manages the MOC for you.  I regularly use one in my projects.  You can see an example in this gist: https://gist.github.com/grantamos/1156fe4d2461dafd9d67

Comment: Does viewDidLoad only get called once?  Ie is there anything I need to know about before just moving that code?

Comment: I can't tell by the small code snippet provided, but you should be fine moving the code provided from awakeFromNib to viewDidLoad.  If you're worried about breaking something, consider moving just navigationController.managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext; to the viewDidLoad method, leaving all of your controller creation in place.

Comment: In respect to your first question, viewDidLoad can be called multiple times.  awakeFromNib is only called once for the lifespan of the view controller.  Check out this stackoverflow post for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9137413/how-often-is-viewdidload-called

Comment: I continually see my viewDidLoad method get called before my prepareForSegue.  Not sure what is going on here, but when that happens there is no why I can set the MOC correctly.

Comment: NM previous comment.  I had layout stuff in my awakeFromNib.  Doing that caused the viewDidLoad to fire right from awakeFromNib (before segue).  I moved all the code to viewDidLoad and it works great.  Better yet I am actually injecting the MOC now, perfect!

Answer (score 0):

`awakeFromNib` is called very early when segueing to a view controller (it's called before anyone outside the storyboard gets a reference to that view controller). Can you just move your code in `awakeFromNib` to a method called later on in the cycle, such as `viewWillAppear:` or `viewDidLoad`? I believe those are both called after `prepareForSegue:`.