# Preventing memory leaks when using instantiateViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am new to ios development so please forgive the ignorance. I noticed that when I'm using the UICollectionViewCell I am able to call dequeueReusableCell to either instantiate or call an existing cell. I was wondering if there is something similar for view controllers. Or if not what would be the right way to prevent re-instantiation of view controllers unnecessarily while navigating around in an app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using **navigationController** e.g. the iPhone has Settings >> General >> About.

When you are in Settings, there is no GeneralVC loaded. When you go to general then you now have SettingVC & GeneralVC but no AboutVC. If you go to About and then come back to General then AboutVC is completely deallocated.

For navigationControllers every time you load a viewController the `viewDidLoad` will get called.

---

For **tabBarControllers**, like your Phone App, all the tabs (Favorites, Recents, Contacts, Keypad, Voicemail) are always in the memory. They won't get deallocated. If you are on KeypadVC, then all other VCs are still in the memory. 
For tabBarControllers every time you load a viewController the `viewWillAppear` will get called. The `viewDidLoad` will get called on the first time it's loaded.

So depending on what you're doing (tabBarController or navigationcontroller) the viewController may or may not exist after you move away from it.

Additionally I find [this comment thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9137413/how-often-is-viewdidload-called/9137795#comment66314111_9137413) and the question related. The question is a bit old yet it helps you better understand some of the older answers and this very question of yours.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean something like ARC (automatic reference counter) which in swift takes control of deallocating every useless part in your app, to reuse memory. You should not bother on this one, because this is fully automatic, for ex. if your vc has been instantiated, and you've moved to another vc arc will deallocate that first vc because there aren't any references to it, and only problem would be if you mistekenly made a connection (reference) to that first vc from some (mostly) closure in your app, then ARC wouldn't remove that vc from memory because connection is still there and ARC knows about it - then you have leaks, and the handy tools to check if every part of your app ui is deallocated correctly are Instruments provided by Apple.

Answer (score 0):

Table and collection cells reuse their views because users often scroll through many items very quickly and tearing down and reallocating memory for each item isn't efficient enough for that to perform well.  The same is not true of view controllers, so this mechanism isn't needed for them.

Having more than one instance of a view controller is fine; it's not a memory leak.