# Do UIViewControllers get destroyed and recreated in iOS during lifecycle events? Or do they simply get "re-attached"?

Tags: ios, swift

Let us consider the following example subclass of a `UIViewController`

```
import Foundation

class CustomViewController: UIViewController 
{
    override func viewDidLoad() 
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) 
    {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }
    
    init()
    {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) 
    {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
}
```

According to [the following stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9137413/how-often-is-viewdidload-called)

> `viewDidLoad(...)` will be called once whenever the view controller needs to load its view hierarchy. Obviously, that'll happen the first time that the controller accesses its view. If the view controller later unloads its view, then `viewDidLoad(...)` will be called again the next time the view is loaded. A view controller won't unload its view just because the view is hidden, but it might do so if memory starts to run low.

But what about the `UIViewController` itself as an object in memory? During low memory events, or when the app has been placed into the background, will the `UIViewController` object simply be discarded and recreated with `init(...)`? Or will it be guaranteed a lifeline and be preserved - so only `viewDidLoad(...)` will be called again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The entire premise of your question is incorrect.

The question and answer you cite are way outdated and wrong. Views are not magically unloaded and reloaded. `viewDidLoad` can never be called more than once by the runtime on a given VC instance, and using it for onetime early lifetime tasks is correct.

As for your question itself: No VC will ever be forcibly destroyed by the runtime due to low memory. If your memory usage is excessive and you fail to reduce it, the runtime does not dismantle piecemeal the object structure of your app; it kills your entire app.

Comment: Do you have a source for the last claim of "the runtime does not dismantle piecemeal the object structure of your app; it kills your entire app"? I am unsure of which answer is right because different stackoverflow posts are saying different things...

Comment: Matt is correct. It gives you a low memory warning, and if you implement code that discards large data structures in response, you can stave off your execution. if you ignore low memory warnings, the system warns you again, and then it kills you.

Comment: The burden is on you to free up memory. The system does not amputate parts of your running app. It warns you, and if you don't free up memory, it pops a cap in your a**.

Answer (score 4):

Adding to Matt's answer:

View controllers get created when it is time to display them, and persist until UIKit is done with them.

The lifecycle of a view controller depends on how you manage it. Often that's based on what kind of parent view controller hosts it.

Some examples (not an exhaustive list)

If a view controller is displayed modally, it is likely created, displayed, and then discarded once it is dismissed.

Navigation controllers manage a "stack" of view controllers. All the view controllers in the stack exist in memory for the whole time they are on the stack. You create a new view controller and push it onto the stack to display it. If you pop one or more view controllers off the stack, the navigation controller releases its strong reference to them, and they will be deallocated unless you keep another strong reference to them somewhere (which is not typical.)

You created all the view controllers that will be displayed in a tab bar controller at the time you create the tab bar controller, and they persist for the life of the tab bar controller.

Page view controllers keep strong references to the page(s) being displayed, and possibly to the next and previous view controller. Other page's view controllers get discarded, and new view controllers are created to display new pages.

As Matt pointed out in his answer, the quote you included about viewDidLoad is out of date and wrong. (I think that was from iOS 3, if memory serves.) A view controller's viewDidLoad method is called once and only once in its lifetime, when it's views are first loaded. The view controller's views will never be deallocated until the view controller itself is deallocated.